# How can same GUID partition table be used in two different internal storage size?

Tags: gpt

I am looking at this mediatek soc that has two configurations 128gb and 64gb. The same GPT binary is being flashed at 0x0 so I don't understand how the same GPT can be used for two varying different sizes. I tried googling but nothing came up.

Comment: We need a little more information. Can you post the partition information for each of the two devices? `fdisk -l /dev/sd?` should be sufficient

Comment: Images come preconfigured with a small system partition and on first boot, there might be an intitialization step where the partitions grow. Or there is a step in the documentation which might show you how to grow the partition manually.

Comment: Raspberry Pi does it too. Random links: https://gijs-de-jong.nl/posts/raspberry-pi-file-system-resize-on-first-boot/ , https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=313003